# How to calculate values from multiple tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014-express

I want to get the values of quantity and amount from store and order detail tables into one table, but the values are not summing up correctly.

Product table

| ProductId | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple |
| 2 | Banana |

Store table

| ID | Name | Qty | Rack | ProductId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Banana | 5 | A | 2 |
| 2 | Apple | 3 | B | 1 |
| 3 | Banana | 2 | C | 2 |

OrderDetail

| ID | Name | Qty | Amount | ProductId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Banana | 1 | 2.00 | 2 |
| 2 | Banana | 2 | 4.00 | 2 |
| 3 | Apple | 1 | 1.00 | 1 |

See code that l had tried

```
SELECT
    Store.Name,
    Sum(Store.Qty) as Store,
    Sum(OrderDetail.Qty) as QtyOrder,
    Sum(OrderDetail.Amount) as Amount
FROM Store
INNER JOIN OrderDetail ON Store.ProductId = OrderDetail.ProductId
GROUP BY Store.Name, OrderDetail.Name
```

Expected output

| Name | Store | QtyOrder | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Banana | 7 | 3 | 6.00 |
| Apple | 3 | 1 | 1.00 |

Comment: What output do you actually get?

Comment: And you are grouping only by store, not fruit

Comment: @Daniel A. White I had also tried by grouping OrderDetail.Name but it's suuming up values by  3times  for both for store and QtyOrder

Comment: Is Store a shortended form of storage 
or is Store meant as a Shop(location)?

Comment: @A.Copter store is the table name (i.e. Storetable)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
with product(id,name) as 
(select 1 , 'Apple' union all
 select 2,  'Banana'),
  
store(ID,Name,Qty,Rack,ProductId) as ( 
select 1,'Banana',  5,  'A',    2 union all
select 2,'Apple',   3,  'B',    1 union all
select 3,'Banana',  2,  'C',    2  ),
  
OrderDetail(ID,Name,Qty,Amount,ProductId) as (
select 1,'Banana',1,2.00,   2 union all
select 2,'Banana',2,4.00,   2 union all
select 3,'Apple',1,1.00,    1 ),

Thestore as (  
select p.Name,
       Sum(s.Qty) as Store
from product p
inner join store s on p.id = s.ProductId 
GROUP BY p.Name ),
  
TheOrder as (
select p.Name, 
       Sum(o.Qty) as QtyOrder,
       Sum(o.Amount) as Amount 
from product p
inner join OrderDetail o on p.id = o.ProductId 
GROUP BY p.Name)
  
select s.name
  ,s.store 
  ,o.QtyOrder
  ,o.Amount
from Thestore s
inner join TheOrder o on s.name = o.name
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/OKmlqzq0

[image]

Comment: your codes work fine as you had supplied using the local data binding. The values in the output table are exactly what l have in my database. I don't know how to rewrite your codes to fdisplay exactly the output shown above. I will very much appreciate it if you can help me to rewrite your code  so that it can populate from my database. Thank you.

Comment: are you familiar with the "with" clause in sql? I would asume that "With Thestore as (  
select p.Name,
       Sum(s.Qty) as Store
from product p
inner join store s on p.id = s.ProductId 
GROUP BY p.Name ),
  
TheOrder as (
select p.Name, 
       Sum(o.Qty) as QtyOrder,
       Sum(o.Amount) as Amount 
from product p
inner join OrderDetail o on p.id = o.ProductId 
GROUP BY p.Name)
  
select s.name
  ,s.store 
  ,o.QtyOrder
  ,o.Amount
from Thestore s
inner join TheOrder o on s.name = o.name" would run on your system. The other part is just to construct sample data